# How does \n work in Char lists in haskell

Tags: list, haskell

right now I have a String equal to `"...\n...\n..."`. In my code I want to write this as a list (like `['a','b','c']`), but how would this work with the \n? I checked in ghci if `string == ['.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.']` and it said no, so does anyone know how I would write the \n's in a Char list, thank you.

Comment: Never tried it, but as `'\n'` I would have thought?

Comment: A `String` is a list of `Char`s, so `"...\n...\n..."` is exactly the same value as `['.','.','.','\n','.','.','.','\n','.','.','.']`

Comment: ik, I just didn't know that '\n' was the correct way to write it, thanks.

Comment: @RobinZigmond it's not all that obvious that the two symbols `\n` in fact represent one character that is on equal footing with `'w'` or `'%'`. This is one of the things that we old programmers take for granted because so many languages do it this way, but for the less experienced this is a rather weird matter.

Comment: @leftaroundabout agreed, and I didn't intend my comment to be condescending. (And reading it back, I don't see how it can be reasonably taken that way - but I apologise to anyone who took it as such, as this was completely unintentional.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `String` is a list of `Char`acters, so `"foo"` and `['f', 'o', 'o']` are *exactly* the same.

For a [*new line* character `'\n'` [wiki]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline#In_programming_languages) you can escape this, so your string `"...\n...\n..."` is equivalent to:

```
['.', '.', '.', '\n', '.', '.', '.', '\n', '.', '.', '.']
```

Here `'\n'` is a *single* character, not *two*: it maps to an ASCII character with codepoint `0a` as hexadecimal value (`10` as decimal value). The compiler thus sees `\n` and replaces that with a single character.

You can thus for example filter with `filter ('\n' /=) some_string` to filter out new line characters from a `String`.